# Cstack_info() output different between Rstudio Server and Rstudio Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: r, memory, rstudio, rstudio-server

I am having trouble getting rid of the CStack limit when running my code.
I managed to get rid of the error by appending

```
* hard stack unlimited
* soft stack unlimited
* soft memlock unlimited
* hard memlock unlimited

root soft stack unlimited
root hard stack unlimited
root soft memlock unlimited
root hard memlock unlimited
```

to `/etc/security/limits.conf` which fixes the problem on RStudio Desktop.

I get the following output from running Cstack_info()

```
> Cstack_info()
      size    current  direction eval_depth 
        NA         NA          1          2
```

This is the output from `ulimit -s` on the desktop terminal

```
coolshades@coolshades-ws:~$ ulimit -s
unlimited
```

Code runs perfectly on RStudio Desktop.

On the **same** machine, I also am running RStudio Server (free) to run code remotely. It would seem that these settings are not sticking when running RStudio Server.

This is the output from Cstack_info() on the RStudio Server

```
> Cstack_info()
      size    current  direction eval_depth 
   7969177      26336          1          2
```

This is the `ulimit` output from terminal on the RStudio Server

```
coolshades@coolshades-ws:~$ ulimit -s
8192
```

I am able to change the limit back to unlimited with `ulimit -s unlimited`. But it will only kick in after Rsession is restarted. However, when I restart the R session, the output of `ulimit -s` reverts back to 8192.

I am out of ideas as to how best to tackle this problem and hope a more experienced RStudio Server user will be able to advise on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

I had to make the following changes to the following files:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/user.conf` add `DefaultLimitSTACK=134217728`

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system.conf` add `DefaultLimitSTACK=134217728`

Make sure the number you define is a power of 2, else Ubuntu fails to login for some reason.

I have 128GB of RAM. So I have set my limit to 2^27.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

DefaultLimitSTACK=134217728 seems to get 128MB of RAM instead of 128GB of RAM, as is shown by system("ulimit -s") in R. The DefaultLimitSTACK seems to take byte as input unit.

However, the change of DefaultLimitSTACK is the key of changing the R studio server c stack usage limit.

Do not forget to reboot your computer, since the change is the system level not the user level or Rstudio server level.